# Plots of functions in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have two functions `x[t]` and `y[t]` which are similar in trend. I want to plot them in the same figure but it is hard to distinguish them. What is the command to plot one of the function in dashed line.

Another question is how to plot the function `x[t]` with different values of some parameter $\alpha$ in the same graph, as in the second figure? [image]

[image]

Comment: Dashed line can be plotted by adding option `PlotStyle->Dashed`. But I doubt here a dashed line would make any difference. A better choice would be plotting the difference of the two functions.

Comment: (1) People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (2) Search for `Table` in the documentation page for `Plot` and follow the example (the last example of the "Basic Examples").

Comment: Another possibility: plot the Log of the functions so you can see the differences more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranges of the functions involved are disparate by orders of magnitude, which makes them hared to plot on one chart. Here is the best I can do without spending hours tinkering with the plots.

```
x[a_][t_] := MittagLefflerE[a, t^a] + MittagLefflerE[a, 3 t^a]
y[a_][t_] := -MittagLefflerE[a, t^a] + MittagLefflerE[a, 3 t^a]
```

Plotting th difference between `x[a][t] - y[a][t]` as suggested by L. Yu.

```
diffXY[a_][t_] := 2 MittagLefflerE[a, t^a]
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    Callout[diffXY[#][t], Row[{"a = ", #}], After] & /@ Range[.2, 1., .2]], {t, 0, 2.5},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {t, HoldForm[x[t] - y[t]]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: diff_plot]

Plotting `x[a][t]` on a double-log-linear plot.

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    Callout[x[#][t], Row[{"a = ", #}], After] & /@ Range[.2, 1., .2]], {t, 0, 2.5},
  PlotRange -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1.25,
  ScalingFunctions -> {Log@*Log, Exp@*Exp},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {t, HoldForm[x[t]]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: x_plot]